# Add random noise to Variable tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am beginner in tensorflow and I have run into a problem: how to manually change Variable? More precisely, I want to add some noise to my Weights tensor, see how good it does, and based on that, apply/ignore the change.

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.randomNormal([xsize,ysize]))

TempW = W + tf.randomNormal([xsize,ysize])

compute = x*TempW

#initialize, run the computation etc.

# how can I make W = TempW now?
```

Comment: `W.assign(TempW)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks! I don't know how I skipped that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to store the result back into an upstream variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After kratenko pointed it out, I figured that there are methods like

```
tf.Variable.assign(value)
tf.Variable.assign_add(value)
tf.Variable.assign_subtract(value)
```

In my case, usage was:

```
#initialisation    
apply = W.assign(TempW)
#usage
sess.run(apply)
```

So if anyone also skipped these ones in docs, I hope it helps.